# Uncaught SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react website when I open it shows white page only. when I check console it says "Uncaught SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal" on vendors~main.chunk.js:7732:72 . In this location I found this line
`var I=function(e,t,n){return e.toLocaleString(t,n);};t=function(){try{0.toLocaleString("i");}catch(e){return "RangeError"===e.name;}` here it seems like error in `0.toLocaleString("i");}catch(e){return "RangeError"===e.name;}` Now the problem I have no idea how this file is build and where did this error coming from. Please help me into this

Comment: you need to debug in source file.

Comment: please can you help me into this I mean where to find it. because In my source code there isn't anything like this

Comment: Run the project locally in your system and then check the console.

Comment: it works perfectlly in my local no error nothing.

Comment: well, you need to provide some source code inorder for us to debug. Just the error won't help. Atleast a link to the app. If you are using webpack, enable source maps using `dev-tool` so that you can find which line is causing issue in prod. `devtool: "eval-source-map"`

Comment: please can we connect over a small call ?

Comment: or somewhere we can chat ?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252168/uncaught-syntaxerror-identifier-starts-immediately-after-numeric-literal-in-rea